# How to install apt packages into mounted system image (img file)

Tags: apt, disk-image, deployment

I need to edit/prepare debian-based Raspbian system image for multiple Raspberry Pi devices.

Until now, my modifications consisted in adding or changing existing config files.

I wrote script like this (to mount partitions from img file):

```
IMGFILE='edited-raspbian.img'
MNTDIR='/mnt/'$IMGFILE'/'
LOOPDEVICE=$(sudo losetup -f)
sudo losetup -P $LOOPDEVICE $IMGFILE

PARTITIONS=$(sudo fdisk -l $LOOPDEVICE | grep $LOOPDEVICE'*p' | cut -d$' ' -f 1 | cut -d$'/' -f 3)

while IFS= read -r PARTITION; do
    MNTDIRPART=$MNTDIR'/'${PARTITION: -2}
    sudo mkdir -p $MNTDIRPART
    sudo mount "/dev/$PARTITION" "$MNTDIRPART"
done <<< "$PARTITIONS"
```

After I run it I see and edit '/' and '/boot' partitions from image in directories:

```
/mnt/edited-raspbian.img/p1
/mnt/edited-raspbian.img/p2
```

---

My question is:

How can I install apt packages "into image"?

Can I just chroot to directory, where image `/` partition is mounted and run `apt install`?

To simplify everything I can work on Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (normally I'm editing these images on latest Debian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I just chroot to directory, where image / partition is mounted and run apt install?

Sure, as long you've correctly configured your system.  Assuming you're mounting the filesystems on something other than a Raspberry Pi, you will need to install `qemu-arm-static`, which is used to run Raspberry Pi binaries on other architectures.

Once that package is correctly installed and configured (which should be taken care of you automatically by the package), you can just `chroot` into the target directory:

```
# chroot /mnt/edited-raspbian.img/p2
```

Note that for a typical Raspberry Pi Os (née Raspbian) image, you'll want to mount partition 1 on `/boot`.  That is, if your raspberry pi image is exposed as `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2`, you would typically:

```
# mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/edited-raspbian.img
# mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/edited-raspbian.img/boot
```

There are some disadvantages to use `chroot`; you will probably need to manually mount `/proc`, `/sys, and possibly` /dev`.  An easier solution is to use` systemd-nspawn`:

```
# systemd-nspawn -D /mnt/edited-raspbian.img
```

This will take care of automatically setting up (and tearing down) the special directories.

Depending on what you're trying to install, you may end up needing to re-size the images. For example, the Raspberry Pi OS "lite" image only has 278MB of space available without resizing.

Comment: Do I really need to mount /boot if I'm working on Raspberry Pi with same OS version as base of my image? Same question about /sys and /dev...

Comment: If you perform an `apt-get update` and `/boot` is not mounted, you'll end up breaking things because your kernel *modules* will get updated but the kernel won't. Things like `/sys` and `/proc` are generally necessary for a variety of commands to operate correctly; it really depends on what you're trying to do. Just using `systemd-nspawn` instead of `chroot` means you don't need to worry about those particular issues.

Comment: Well, I need to install things like MySQL, Java, gcc. I don't think they need to change anything in kernel, however thanks for good explanation why this is needed. Regarding sys and proc - this will be mounted from "real" same version Raspbian system where I will work.